# remove "items 1-9 of X" from google result

Tags: google

the results of my Magento based website's categories includes "**items 1 - 9 of X**" before the actual description of the category.
How can I get rid of this? In this snapshot, what I want to delete is the red rectangle
[image: snapshot]

**edits**:
@Su, these are the reason:

1. Having text like (Items 1 - 9 of 144 –) appear in a Google listing uses up the 25 word limit that Google allows us.
2. More importantly, the first few words of the description can persuade or dissuade someone from visiting my site. This text will not positively influence people to visit my site.

@DisgruntledGoat this information shows up in the source code of that page, like this:

```
<table class="toolbar" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="pager" style="width: 414px;">
            <table class="pager" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Items 1 to 9 of 144 total</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As with most of the rich snippets, you're probably asking the wrong question if you want control over it appearing at all. If you're not doing anything special and this information is showing up already, it's unlikely you have much say in that regard. However, you might be able to [*influence*](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146750) the information some. You should consider editing your question to explain why you object to this showing up.

Comment: @Su This is quite interesting, Google are picking up a very odd section of text on the page, where they usually display the access time they are instead displaying the page number http://www.weddingrings.net/unique-rings.html

Comment: Did you remove the pagination from the page? Because I don't see anything that even suggests you have 144 items.

Comment: @Su' and DisgruntledGoat thank you for your comments, I have edited the question to include the information you asked.

Answer (score 2):

In looking over your source, it appears that the **1 to 9 of X** is the first real content encountered by the crawler.  The only suggestion I have is to try making the `td` a `th` in the hopes that the crawler will go after the content and not the label.

Comment: That's as good of a suggestion as any.

Comment: thanx for taking the time to look into this Joshua: I will see what I can do about this and I'll get back to you. (sorry for late answer, I was on holliday)

Comment: @OSdave any luck with this issue?